# Vertically positioning text relative and rotated 90°

Tags: css

I'm unsure if there is a property that does this. But I'm looking to add text vertically in a div  on this website- http://chazsouthard.org/. However I want the text to appear to be rotated 90° clockwise.

I attached a screenshot from Photoshop as a example for what I'm trying to accomplish.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CSS3 I believe you are looking for `transform: rotate(90deg);`

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a negative number here to achieve the orientation you desire. Adding the prefixed versions as well for cross-browser compatibility. simple codepen: http://codepen.io/BuoyantMedia/pen/Asdmr

```
transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
```